# Remove debugging error while generating multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to loop through a range for creating a list of names which will be used to generate multiple sheets having the names in the list, However, after completion of the sheet generation and rename process another sheet having the same name of the template sheet is being generated and I am getting a debugging error. Can any one fix the code.

```
Sub Generate_Sheets()

  Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, c As Range
  Set sh1 = Sheets("SPT-Liq")
  Set sh2 = Sheets("Combine")

   Range("A4:A600").Select
   Selection.AutoFilter
   ActiveSheet.Range("$A$5:$A$116").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
   Range("A4:A64").Select
   Range("A4:A64").Select
   Range("A4:A600").Select
   Range("A116").Activate
   Selection.Copy
   Range("AT5").Select
   Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   Selection.AutoFilter

      For Each c In sh2.Range("AT5", sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, 46).End(xlUp))
      sh1.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
      ActiveSheet.Name = c.Value
    
 Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: You might like to show which line the error is occurring. 
What comes to my mind is that the worksheet name (for the worksheet you just added by the Sheet.Copy command) is invalid or already existing.
I couldn't find a Microsoft site for the naming rules (characters/words to avoid, etc) but there are lots of links out there; just Google.
(the name can't be blank, or over 31 chars, or one of these: \/?*[]:, for example)

Comment: The error is shown in line "ActiveSheet.Name = c.Value" after generation of all sheets based on list

Comment: Hit the DEBUG button and then provide to us the value of “c.Value” …!

Comment: I already hit the debug value is "SPT-Liq: which is the template sheet that is being copied SWBH 30 is from the list of sheetnames used. After that no sheet name exists

Comment: Can we modify the code where it will count the numbers from the rang ("AT5", sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, 46).End(xlUp) and accordingly generate those number of additional sheets and then change the names of the additional sheets excluding "Combine" named sheet and the mother template sheet

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the c.Value? is the double-quote character (") part of it? is the colon character (:) part of it? these are not acceptable in the worksheet names.

Comment: Maybe you can insert this line right below the **For Each** statement:
**debug.print "|" & c.Value & "|"**
and run, then show us what is printed in the immediate window?

Comment: The colon character is part of the name, but double quote is not

Comment: It does not work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Application.Screenupdating = False will solve the issue